# Word makes author of comment anonymous, when saving the file

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm using Word for o365. When a document is saved, Word replaces the name of the comment's author with "Author". When Autosave is enabled, this happens right after adding the comment. How can this behaviour be disabled?

Comment: Did you check your Trust Center / Privacy Options / Document specific settings section; I think if "Remove personal information from file properties on save" is ticked it'll anonymise track changes/comments to "Author".